# Using ternary and colon in for loop

Tags: php

This is from a tutorial for php,  I cant understand the use of the ternary ? And the use of the colon :
Can you please  explain to me the use of the colon in here thanks 
I tried to read the tutorial and php reference but couldn't understand it

This code will print a side way pyramid

```
 for ($row = 1; $row <= 5; $row++)
  {
      for ($col = 1; $col <= ($row > 3 ? 6 - $row : $row); $col++)
      {
          echo '*';
      }

      echo "<br>";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as the following code:

```
for ($row = 1; $row <= 5; $row++)
{
    if ($row > 3)
        $max = 6 - $%row;
    else 
        $max = $row;

    for ($col = 1; $col <= $max; $col++)
    {
        echo '*';
    }

    echo "<br>";
}
```

The colon is part of the ternary operator:

```
A ? B : C
```

equals to

```
if (A) then B else C
```

For more information please check the documentation on the [ternary (`?:`) operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: So the ":" is "else"

Comment: @PhpL yes, the `:` is the same as `else`.

Comment: Thanks tom and pharaoh

Comment: you added '$%row;' a % before row why is that, sorry a question led into another ?

Answer (score 0):

ternary if:

```
/* most basic usage */
$var = 5;
$var_is_greater_than_two = ($var > 2 ? true : false); // returns tru
```

Makes coding simple if/else logic quicker
You can do your if/else logic inline with output instead of breaking your output building for if/else statements
Makes code shorter
Makes maintaining code quicker, easier

read below article for more examples:

https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators